# How do I create a path in the middle of two paths?

Tags: inkscape

How do I create a path that is in the middle of the space between two other paths? This new path should be the same distance to each of the existing two paths.

In the sketch I made, the green lines are the ones I already have. The red line is the one I want to generate.

[image: Path between 2 other paths]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PaoloGibellini answered my question. I just used the [interpolate](https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/interpolate/tutorial-interpolate.html) function, and it seemed to work fine.

Select the two lines, then go to Extensions > Generate from Path > Interpolate

Here is a video of it in action. I wasn't able to record the menu unfortunately.
[image: interpolate.gif]

You can make multiple midlines by changing the number of interpolate steps.

Comment: Please, add a screenshot of your work and some hints to help other people, then mark as "Answered" your question.

Comment: I agree with @PaoloGibellini - doing this will result in a much better, more useful answer. It also increases your chances of more votes too! :)